# Log specific errors with Apache2

Tags: linux, debian, apache2, php-7

In order to protect the website, there is some rules in .htaccess

```
# Rules to disable XML-RPC
<files xmlrpc.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</files>
```

This works perfectly and produces an error log in /var/log/apache2/mysite.error.log

```
AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/mysite/xmlrpc.php
```

**I want this kind of specific errors be logged in another file** (i.e. /var/log/apache2/mysite.deny.log)

I tried :

```
# Rules to disable XML-RPC
<files xmlrpc.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.deny.log
</files>
```

But crash the server^^
What is the problem ?

Errorlog in .htaccess not possible ?
Errorlog in <files> section is not correct ?
Is there a solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try without slash only the file name. As per the docs ErrorLog logs/error_log (Unix) . The error log directive sets the name of the file to which the server will log any errors it encounters. If the file-path does not begin with a slash (/) then it is assumed to be relative to the ServerRoot. If the file-path begins with a pipe (|) then it is assumed to be a command to spawn to handle the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer^^ According to the Apache2 doc :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#errorlog

Context = server config, virtual host

No ErrorLog in .htaccess file

No ErrorLog in <files> section